# How to copy column from one table to another using JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

What is wrong with the following **PostgreSQL** query?

```
UPDATE project_project SET  project_project.create_date = assignments.start_date  
FROM project_project
LEFT JOIN account_analytic_account ON account_analytic_account.id = project_project.analytic_account_id
LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.accounts_ref = account_analytic_account.id
```

gives

```
[SQL] UPDATE project_project SET  project_project.create_date = assignments.start_date  
FROM project_project
LEFT JOIN account_analytic_account ON account_analytic_account.id = project_project.analytic_account_id
LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.accounts_ref = account_analytic_account.id

[Err] ERROR:  table name "project_project" specified more than once
```

I tried,

```
UPDATE pp SET  pp.create_date = am.start_date  
FROM project_project as pp
LEFT JOIN account_analytic_account as aa ON aa.id = pp.analytic_account_id
LEFT JOIN assignments as am ON am.accounts_ref = aa.id
```

gives

```
[SQL] UPDATE pp SET  pp.create_date = am.start_date  
FROM project_project pp
LEFT JOIN account_analytic_account aa ON aa.id = pp.analytic_account_id
LEFT JOIN am ON am.accounts_ref = aa.account_analytic_account.id

[Err] ERROR:  relation "pp" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE pp SET  pp.create_date = am.start_date
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems to avoid:

1- in SET column=value, do not prepend a table name or alias to `column`. It yields an error and is useless anyway, since `UPDATE tablename` is only able to update columns from `tablename`. An alias of tablename can be used in other places, but not in the SET clause.

2- don't repeat the name of the table to update in the rest of the query unless you want to specifically induce a secondary and uncorrelated scan of this table.

Here is my proposal of a modified query that I hope does what you intend:

```
UPDATE project_project pp SET create_date =
 (select assignments.start_date  FROM account_analytic_account LEFT JOIN assignments
  ON assignments.accounts_ref = account_analytic_account.id
 WHERE 
 account_analytic_account.id = pp.analytic_account_id);
```